# Issue in python code, unable to find issue

Tags: python-3.x

while trying to create a custom map loader from a file, i get the following issue:

```
"D:\Python 3.4\python.exe" "D:/Games in Python/Game1/game.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Games in Python/Game1/game.py", line 60, in <module>
    game = Game()
  File "D:/Games in Python/Game1/game.py", line 4, in __init__
    world = World()
  File "D:/Games in Python/Game1/game.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "D:/Games in Python/Game1/game.py", line 54, in load
    self.map_data[a][z][y][x] = self.tmp4[x]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried debugging it myself by printing some parts of the list, and going through the program step by step, but still no success. here's the code:

```
    self.map = open("Data/Saves/test.txt" , "r")
    self.map_dat = self.map.read()
    self.map.close

    self.tmp1 = self.map_dat.split("-")
    self.map_data = [None] * 2
    for a in range(0, 2):
        self.tmp2 = self.tmp1[a].split(">")
        self.map_data[a] = [None] * 4
        for z in range(0, 4):
            self.tmp3 = self.tmp2[z].split("\n")
            self.map_data[a][z] = [None] * 100
            for y in range(0, 100):
                self.tmp4 = self.tmp3[y].split(",")
                self.map_data[a][z][y] = [None] * 100
                for x in range(0, 100):
                    self.map_data[a][z][y][x] = self.tmp4[x]
```

the map file is as follows:

```
map_lvl0
>
map_lvl1
>
map_lvl2
>
map_lvl3
-
map_lvl0_properties
>
map_lvl1_properties
>
map_lvl2_properties
>
map_lvl3_properties



where map_lvl(0 to 3) a 100*100 grid of zeros seperated by ","
```

Sorry for giving such a strange description of the map file as i couldn't upload the actual file here

I would really appreciate any help in this matter, any way of making it cleaner, shorter, etc

Comment: If you are using PyCharm, press `shift` + `F9` and then mouseover `self.map_data` to see its contents.

Comment: One of lists you're trying to access has less elements that you expect it to have. Try printing `len(self.map_data[a][z][y])` and `len(self.tmp4)` before doing actual assignments. You'll see which list has less elements than expected.

Comment: hmm, just before the error occures print(len(self.tmp4) ) shows 1 instead of 100. let me try re making the map file

Comment: hmm, @Lukasz Rogalski i tried redoing the map file from scratch but the same error still persists. seems like i must have made an error in the way the program reads the map. by the looks of it the problem occures in the z for loop as the program seems to print about hundred "100's" before showing the error of "1" while printing len(self.tmp4)

Comment: @Madworks The debugger is indeed an extremely useful tool. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJtWxm12Eo0)'s a short tutorial.

Comment: i finally found the problem, it was with the map,after every ">" there was a newline, so this caused the problem. corrected that and now the program works fine. Thanks for the help @Frrmi paradox and Lukasz Rogalski

Comment: btw the video really helped me understand debug mode better, seems to be a very powerful tool. thanks a lot

Comment: @Madworks Glad to be of help :) (i ll delete this comment later on, since on SO we remove all comments that are of no use to future visitors; only content that is relevant to the topic is supposed to be posted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is probably in lines on the outer edges of a grid, aka a `tmp2` entry like "\nthe actual data\n", which doesn't start with a row since the whitespace wasn't trimmed off. Or it could be that the properties field doesn't exist out of a numerical matrix.

However this map format is probably not the best way to store your data. 
Personally I'd go a binary format for effectiveness or for a JSON file (for readability, and simply parsable with `json`). Something like:

```
[
    {
        "map_name" : "some name",
        "map_prop2" : "some value",
        ...
        "map_layout" : [
            [0,...,0],
            ...,
            [0,...,0]
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

If you insist with the current format I'd go with a function like this (*NOTE*: you didn't tell us the format of the properties, so I just kept it as a single string, parse them in the actual solution):

```
# Returns a dictionairy
# lvls[map_name] -> { id : int, properties : string, grid : int[][] }
def read_map(filename):
    lvls = {}

    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        lvls_data, lvls_props = f.read().split("-")

        lvls_data  = [ s.strip() for s in lvls_data.split(">") ]
        lvls_props = [ s.strip() for s in lvls_props.split(">") ]

        assert(len(lvls_data) == len(lvls_props))

        for i in range(len(lvls_data)):
            # I had no idea how to parse the properties, since I don't know the
            # format. So I kept it plaintext, do actually parse them

            data, properties = lvls_data[i], lvls_props[i]
            grid = [ [ int(point) for point in line.split(",") ] for line in data.split("\n") ]

            # assert all dimensions are in order
            assert(len(grid) == 100)
            assert(all(len(grid[i]) == 100 for i in range(100)))

            lvls["map%i" % i] = { 'id' : i, 'properties': properties, 'grid' : grid}
    return lvls
```

**NOTE I had no way to properly test this, so use with caution**

Comment: well, i found my problem, and yes it was just what you said, the whitespace, correcting that seems to solve it, thx. btw i'm creating a sort of dwarf fortress game, trying to use my current knowledge to see how to make a similar game. so any advice ?

Comment: Sorry, dont know too much about making games. (also haven't played that game)